# How can I take on input with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to use argparse, and I would take on input some values with argparse.

(I'm using Python 2.7)

Until now this is my code:

```
username = raw_input ( "username: " )
password = raw_input ( "password: " )
parser.add_argument( username )
parser.add_argument( password )
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.string()
```

It returns `error: too few arguments`.

I know that it's all wrong, but I cannot understand how to do it.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Argparse is for command line arguments, while raw_input reads stdin.

Comment: You should be targeting Python 3 now anyway, unless you have a very specific reason you need to target legacy systems (in which please tag with [tag:python-2.7] explicitly).

Comment: thanks @tripleee, I will!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example. Basically after you call parse_args() the arguments end up inside of args.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('filename', help='Positional, must have')
    parser.add_argument('bucket', help='Positional, must have')
    parser.add_argument('--credFile', help='Optional use double dash')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    somefunction(args.bucket, args.filename, args.credFile)
```

Comment: I would have another question: if I don't write arguments, so I just writ `python myfile.py` , after doing `args = parser.parse_args()` it rightly returns `error: too few arguments`.
How can I save this error and make it visible only if I want to?

Comment: It should be fine to have no args passed, right? Did you configure it with required args?

Comment: No, I hadn't passed him args; passing them it works as desired. thank you!